# How to toggle a rectangle grid using react-leaflet's LayerControl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to show or hide a grid of rectangles (the overlay) over a map (the base layer).

I'm using the react Leaflet layers control : [doc](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components#layerscontrol)

Problem : My grid shows all the time even if I uncheck the check box

My grid :

[image: grid picture]

```
class Grid extends MapControl {
    createLeafletElement(props) {
        const { 
          leaflet: { map },
        } = props;

        const minLng = -4.89;  
    const minLat = 41.29;  
    const maxLng = 9.65;   
    const maxLat = 51.22

    const nbColumn = 10;
    const nbRow = 10;
    const rectWidth  = maxLng - minLng;
    const rectHeight = maxLat - minLat;

    const incrLat  = rectHeight  / nbColumn;
    const incrLng = rectWidth / nbRow;
    let column = 0;
    let lngTemp = minLng;
    let latTemp = minLat;

        let rect;
        const arrRect = [];
        while (column < nbColumn) {
          let row = 0;
          latTemp = minLat;
          while (row < nbRow) {
            const cellBounds = [[latTemp, lngTemp], [latTemp + incrLat, lngTemp + incrLng]];
            rect = L.rectangle(cellBounds, {color: "#1EA0AA", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
            arrRect.push(rect);
            latTemp += incrLat; 
            row += 1;
          }
          lngTemp += incrLng;
          column += 1;
        }
        return rect;
    }
}
```

In my leaflet component :

```
class Leaflet extends Component {
   ...
render() {
  return (
      <Map 
         <LayersControl>
            <LayersControl.BaseLayer name="Open Street Map" checked="true">
                <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
                           contributors'
                           url={this.state.url}
                 />
            </LayersControl.BaseLayer>

            <LayersControl.Overlay name="Grid1">
               <LayerGroup>
                  <Grid />     
              </LayerGroup>
            </LayersControl.Overlay>
      </LayersControl>
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not using [a `GridLayer`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components#gridlayer)?

Comment: I've never used it. It's not possible to use layer control with my Grid that extends MapControl ? (I've edited my post with my grid view)

Comment: I want to make a grid Layer such that each rectangle have the same dimension and everytime I click on them there is an event that popup

Comment: What are the values for `column`, `nbColumn` and all the other variables inside `Grid` comp. Can you provide them to be able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Ok I have edited my post with the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not manage to load your grid so I provide another simpler grid example.

To control the Grid's visibility you need to use `react-leaflet`'s `updateLeafletElement` method to trigger prop changes on your custom react-leaflet component. Pass a showGrid prop to be able to control Grid's visibility.

```
updateLeafletElement(fromProps, toProps) {
    const { map } = this.props.leaflet;
    if (toProps.showGrid !== fromProps.showGrid) {
      toProps.showGrid
        ? this.leafletElement.addTo(map)
        : this.leafletElement.removeFrom(map);
    }
  }
```

then in your map component listen to leaflet's overlayadd & overlayremove to be able to toggle a local flag which will control the visibility of the grid using an effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
    map.on("overlayadd", (e) => {
      if (e.name === "Grid1") setShowGrid(true);
    });

    map.on("overlayremove", (e) => {
      if (e.name === "Grid1") setShowGrid(false);
    });
  }, []);


  <LayersControl.Overlay
          checked={showGrid}
          name="Grid1"
        >
          <LayerGroup>
            <Grid showGrid={showGrid} />
          </LayerGroup>
  </LayersControl.Overlay>
```

**Edit**:
The App component as class based component it will look like this:

```
export default class AppWithNoHooks extends Component {
  state = {
    showGrid: false
  };

  mapRef = createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    const map = this.mapRef.current.leafletElement;
    map.on("overlayadd", (e) => {
      if (e.name === "Grid1") this.setState({ showGrid: true });
    });

    map.on("overlayremove", (e) => {
      if (e.name === "Grid1") this.setState({ showGrid: false });
    });
  }
 ...
```

I don't get the error you mentioned.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-toggle-react-leaflet-layer-control-and-rectangle-grid-f43xi?file=/src/App.js:1057-1309)

Comment: I can't use  useEffect() I'm using a class for my leaflet component. After reading the react doc about hooks, I'm using your map.on("overlayadd") and map.on("overlayremove")  on both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate but I'm having this error : TypeError: this.map.on is not a function. console.log(this.map) returns me the map object

Comment: I included a version with a class based App component both on the demo and answer. Please check again.

Comment: I use callback Refs for my map like this :  ref={ref => { this.map = ref;}}  and using it like that : this.map.on("overlayadd")  but I'm still getting TypeError: this.map.on is not a function, console.log(this.map) returns me the map object. My component hierarchy is : Grid < Leaflet < MapView

Comment: You shouldn't use it like this. Use it as in my example. Check the demo example I provided. You should not use the mspRef to listen on map events change but rather `mapRef.current.leafletElement`

Comment: You have confused the map instance with the map dom element reference.